# Does my entity-relationship diagram reflect the relevant business rules?

Tags: database-design, erd

I'm new to database design and I need some critiques, feedback, suggestions, advice, etc. regarding a) some business rules, b) the entity-relationship diagram I have developed to represent them, and c) whether or not they "match".

**Business rules**

The relevant business rules are as follow:

1. Users can rate multiple businesses
2. A business can fall under more than one category
3. Users can comment on multiple businesses
4. Businesses can have zero to many ratings
5. Businesses can have zero to many comments
6. A business can only be located in one and only one city
7. A city can have multiple businesses
8. A category can have multiple businesses
9. Users can have one or more checkins for businesses
10. Businesses can have zero to many checkins

**My entity-relationship diagram**

And I have represented them in the diagram below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a table between Cities -> Business, and a table between Categories and Business.

This way since city can have many business keeping it all in the single table you are breaking the 2nd Normal Form which is suggesting that the groups of data shouldnt be repeated within a table. What that means is that for instance if you have City of New York that has multiple business you will have 2+ records with the same City name but different City ID.

Therefore i would keep the table cities with metadata about the **City only** and add a new table *CityBusiness* with its own identity **id** and **c_id** and **b_id** OR since cities can have only one business (is it possible for one business to expand and open its office to another city?) you can have a primary key defined as combination of **b_id** and **c_id**.

The same rule applies for the Categories. A new table *BusinessCategory* with **ca_id and b_id**, and a Category table with metadata related to category itself.

Answer (score 4):

First - I agree with S4V1N completely on the `Category`-`Business` link - you need a table in between, as each business can have many categories, and each category could be tied to many businesses.

However, as the rules are currently stated, I don't think you need a table between `City` and `Business`. I think you've got `City` laid out wrong.

Currently, each business must be in one and only one city, and each city can be home to multiple businesses. For that, the `City` table should not have a `B_ID` column, as a city is tied to no one business. (I also see no reason for it to have a `U_ID` column, as no relationship between `User` and `City` has been established. I suspect a cut-and-paste issue.) `Business`, however, *should* have a `CI_ID` for the city it's in.

Also - the way I read the diagram, it looks like each user must have at least one `Comment`, `Rating`, and `Checkin`. The rules explicitly indicate "one or more" checkins per user, so that appears correct. However, it doesn't look to me like the user is required to have any comments or ratings - so shouldn't those two be linked with the "0 or more" connector?